# Mysql comments table in relation to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

As there can be comments under basically anything, I am not sure how to transfer the relation into my database design schema.

```
    CREATE TABLE comments (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    authorId INT(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(authorId) REFERENCES users(id)
    );
```

As you can see comments also do have a relation to the users table by storing the author's id in the dataset. However, the comment itself can be under either a post or a video, which are two separate tables.
Here's my question: Should I create a junction table for both relations (video_comments and post_comments) or should I do it in any other way. In addition there should be a ON DELETE CASCADE constraint which should cause a video which is being removed also remove the comments related to it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could create `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` to let you know this id belongs to which table 
as for this part

> In addition there should be a ON DELETE CASCADE constraint which should cause a video which is being removed also remove the comments related to it

I don't know how to do this, I think if i were in your position I will handle it using the code before I delete a video I will check if there are any comments and delete it.

Comment: "I don't know how to do this, I think if i were in your position I will handle it using the code before I delete a video I will check if there are any comments and delete it." Dont suggest a code "workaround" that can cause **race conditions**

Comment: Worth to note, that your solution makes is impossible to use foreign key constraints as they cannot point to two (or more) different tables nut only one.

Comment: @raymond-nijland i just suggest workaround if you think there's better way i will be happy to know it.

Comment: @sticky-bit yeah you are right, I think we could only use unique constraints with both commentable_id and commentable_type

Comment: "i just suggest workaround if you think there's better way i will be happy to know it. " You already copy, paste and quote the beter way in your answer.. Never use database client application code to handle something MySQL natively supports with the InnoDB engine.. For MyISAM engine there is a other method to "simulate" MySQL support deletes from multiple tables ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html )  Something like this should work "fine" for MyISAM engine `DELETE video.*, comment.* FROM video LEFT JOIN comment WHERE video.id = comment.video_id WHERE video.id = <id>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you may want to consider:

1. add a column named as 'itme_id' or something like that to store
   video_id or post_id
2. Lcreate `for/after delete triggers` on both video
   and post tables, do the deletion on your comment table inside the
   trigger using info from the magic table.

In this way, you don't have to create a new table or stick with the cascade thing. This is just my assumption, please let me know if this makes sense to you.

Comment: The point is that I want to use a FOREIGN KEY really badly, but thus I cannot create one since it cannot point to multiple tables and it needs a workaround. What are the benefits of using your method over mine that I should consider using yours?

Comment: @Gabo  I will list the differences between our methods, but it does not mean that either yours or mine is better: 1, need to create triggers on video and posts tables. 2, no foreign key needed on comments table, no need to create more comment tables. 3, need to add one new column to comments table to point back to the unique identifier for either video or post.

Comment: How is your method compared to creating multiple columns for the ids (videoId, postId) and all except for one are leaved blank(null). This way I have for all of them a column which points to a real table with a foreign key so I can make use of the built in advantages.

Comment: @Gabo Sure. You can create another table to collect the unique identifier for videos/posts so that you can use the foreign key. But you still need to take care about the data in video and post tables (I am assuming that you still have separate tables for those two